# Kali Linux wireless card not working

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, kali-linux

I am new to Linux so please bare with me. 
I preformed a fresh install of Kali Linux on my laptop,so now the only operating system available is Kali Linux.

**Here's my problem:** My laptop cannot connect to the Internet through the already built-in wireless card.
My laptop wireless card is: `Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 2x2 AGN` and although the system says that it using the kernal drivers for `iwlwifi` there is still no wireless Internet connection. 

I tried changing the interfaces file under `/etc/network/interfaces`
 and added: 

`# The primary network interfaces` 
`auto wlan0` 
`allow-hotplug wlan0` 
`iface wlan0 inet dhcp` 
Still no luck.

Here's the `ifconfig` details:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.77  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::223:18ff:febe:ab8e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:23:18:be:ab:8e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 27689  bytes 27448393 (26.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15299  bytes 1495734 (1.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xd4600000-d4620000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2460  bytes 187820 (183.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2460  bytes 187820 (183.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:27:10:94:a8:3c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Here's the `iwconfig` details:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"ATT653"  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

**NOTE:** For the ESSID, I manually added "ATT653" using

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
iwconfig wlan0 essid "ATT653"
dhclient wlan0
```

This didn't work because my network is WPA2 encrypted.

Here's the wireless card information:

```
root@kali:~# lspci
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 (rev 35)
```

and

```
root@kali:~# lspci -vq
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 2x2 AGN
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Memory at d4400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [e0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-27-10-ff-ff-94-a8-3c
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Please help me get this issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `sources.list` :

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

add the following line:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

then install `iwlwifi` driver:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi
rmmod iwlwifi
modprobe iwlwifi
```

**edit**

Use the [retired repo](http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories):

```
deb http://old.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
```

Comment: nope it did not work. This is what gets displayed on Terminal http://pastebin.com/UuHsWY8p